# MySQL Query Parent Child

Tags: php, mysql, parent-child, parent

I am working with mysql and php and have a Parent Child  table created in mysql.
Every parent has 3 Childs. Every Child becomes also a Parent and has also 3 Childs and so on.

Now I need to write a function that gives me the last parent in the tree (depending on the selected parent ID) that does not have 3 Childs. So the next Child subscription can be dedicated to that parent.

Can this be done with mysql query or function?

Thanks,
M

---

I use the following query:

```
SELECT t1.uid, t2.pid FROM cms_users AS t1 LEFT JOIN cms_users AS t2 ON t1.uid = t2.pid
```

Which gives mr the following output:

```
t1.uid t2.pid
1      1 
1      1 
1      1 
2      2 
2      2 
2      2 
3      3 
4      NULL 
5      NULL
```

What I actualy need is a result like:

```
p1.uid p2.pid 
1      3 
2      3 
3      1 
4      0 
5      0
```

This result also starts from the root Parent 1 
I need to get the results starting from a selected uid somewhere in the three.
Every parent has his own tree starting from his uid.
Probably I need to write a stored procedure or something but this is all new to me and I don't know how to do this.

This is an example of how the tree looks like. http://www.musafreaks.com/images/tree.jpg
User ID 1 has his own tree, even user 2, 3 and 4 have there own tree and so on.

Comment: What does "depending on the selected parent ID" mean? Could you please post a sample recordset and a desired output of the query?

Comment: Hope this one help:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064913/achieve-hierarchy-in-a-less-number-of-mysql-queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is not trivial to solve within MySQL. Multiple strategies to manage hierarchical data are described in the [manual](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). The rest of my answer is based on this article.

Your setup is sort of a "Adjacency List Model", so you could adapt the `LEFT JOIN` solution for your dataset.

```
SELECT t1.name FROM
category AS t1 LEFT JOIN category as t2
ON t1.category_id = t2.parent
WHERE t2.category_id IS NULL;
```

This assumes that the `parent` field of the root node is `null`. Your possible new parent will be selected as `t1`. Note that this query will return all nodes which have **no** children, if you want to "fill" up each node with three children you'll have to extend the query a bit.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your feedback. Unfortunelly I was not 100% correct in my explanation. What I want is the next parent that has no 3 childs. If he has less then 3 childs he should be available in the list. The search need also to be started at a certain selected parent ID. For example if I select a parent 10 levels deep in the tree it should give me the next parent (in the seleted parents tree. Every parrent has his own tree) that does not have 3 childs assigned.